# 2D object array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

2D arrays such as:`Cell **scoreTable`.After allocating:

```
scoreTable = new Ceil*[10]; 
for(int i = 0 ;i<10;i++) 
scoreTable[i] = new Ceil[9];
```

And I want to save the value like this:`scoreTable[i][j]= new Ceil(i,j)` in heap,and this can not work in c++.Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you considered using a nested `std::vector<std::vector<Cell> >` instead?

Comment: read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've allocated your array like this, you'll already have a 2D array of `Cell`, so you don't need to use the `new` keyword to change the value.

If you give your `Cell` class a method like `SetValue(i,j)`, then you can use it like this: `scoreTable[i][j].SetValue(i,j);`

Comment: I thought too much,thank you ,just add a new method ,it is good.

Answer (score 1):

`scoreTable[i][j]= new Ceil(i,j)`. You are trying to put `Cell*` into Cell.

You have to create 2d array of pointers:

```
auto scoreTable = new Ceil**[10]; 
for(int i = 0 ;i<10;i++) 
    scoreTable[i] = new Ceil*[9];
```

But much better is to use `vector`:

```
std::vector< std::vector<Ceil*> > table;
table.resize(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    table[i].resize(9, NULL);
}
table[3][4] = new Ceil();
```

Comment: I know this ,but it should make a lot of changes because this question appears when I convert java to C++,scoreTable is a Class Member.Thanks all the same.

Comment: It will cause not that many changes, as `vector` overloads `operator[]` and therefore acts like an array.

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest using `std::vector` instead. It is much easier to keep track of.

You can replace all of the code above with

```
std::vector< std::vector< Cell> > scoreTable(10, std::vector<Cell>(9));
```

This will create `scoreTable`, which is a vector containing 10 elements of `vector<Cell>`, each containing 9 cells. In other word, the desired 2D table.

You access the elements in the same way. `scoreTable[i][j]`, where i goes fron 0 to 9, and j from 0 to 8.

If you want to expand with a new row, just say:

```
 scoreTable.push_bach(std::vector<Cell>(9));
```

For a new column:

```
for(size_t row = 0; row < scoreTable.size(); ++row) {
  scoreTable[row].push_back(Cell());
}
```

No need for `new` or `delete`.